# Cascade delete model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars_available, dependent: :destroy
end

class CarsAvailable < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :city
end
```

I have two models Car and City, and a third model CarsAvailable which stores which particular cars are available in a particular City.

How to set a DESTROY association between a Car and CarsAvailable so that when a Car is removed then corresponding CarsAvailable entry also get deleted.

I figured it out for City but a little ambiguous how to apply it to Car.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars_available, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Add association to your `Car` and tell it to destroy association, just like you did with `City`.

Comment: It is not making sense, because of how you named your "many-to-many relationship" table. Rails has done a great job of letting us define our models that reflect our business domain, but you can't forget that it is just code. And you have to understand what `has_many` does, as opposed to how it "reads".

Comment: In present scenario can you please advice me better suitable name for many-to-many relationship, as based on the above scenario

Comment: The first name that came to mind is usually the best fit. So leave the name as is and simply add that `has_many` to your `Car` model.